# Searching in a large dataset (Stays in boxes => Meetings)

Tags: mysql, database, hadoop, dataset, bigdata

I am working on a model of social interactions in mice. I have mice and boxes and a simulation that outputs which mouse stays in which box during which time period. The problem is how to obtain, in the end and from this, the meetings of two mice which were in the same box in an overlapping period.

Right now I have a MySQL database where the simulation directly inserts each stay result. And then another tool,written in Scala, just retrieves all stay result, in portions of a few hundred, loops through them and for each asks the database which stays were overlapping with it, and inserts each pair into the database, like this:

```
`box`,`id1`, `res_id1`, `id2`, `res_id2`, `from`, `to`, `dt`, `typ`
```

This means that mice id1 and id2 were in the box "box" in the interval between "from" and "to" with duration "dt" and the meetings was of type "typ". There could be four types of meetings depending on when each mouse was in the box (e.g. when the one entered and exited relative to the other). "res_id1" and "res_id2" tell which stay results were used to generate the meeting result.

Obviously, this is very inefficient. What would be a better way of doing it? I am not constrained to using a RDMS, but I though this would be the easiest as I am reading and further analysing the data in R afterwards. Would it make sense to output the stays in a text file and then use Hadoop to generate the meetings somehow? Or anything else?

For the duration of an approximately one quarter of one trial of the simulation I generate around 1.5 million stay results.